# Sub, Function or Property error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to load , sort and display names from an excel document. I keep getting an expected sub, function or property error?

```
Sub load()   'this program purpose is to load , sort and display names from an excel document'
    Dim names(1 To 5) As String
    Dim passNum As Integer, i As Integer, temp As String
    Dim num_names As Long, shift As String

num_names = 4  ' LOADS NAMES FROM EXCEL FILE'
For i = 1 To num_names
    names(i) = Cells(i, 1)
Next i
Call shift
Call display
End Sub

Sub sort_1(passNum As Integer, num_names As Long, i As Integer, temp As String)' SORTS NAMES'
   For passNum = 1 To (num_names - 1)
    For i = 1 To (num_names - passNum)
       If names(i) > names(i + 1) Then
            temp = names(i)
            names(i) = names(i + 1)
            names(i + 1) = temp
       End If
    Next i
Next passNum
End Sub

Sub display(i As Integer, num_names As Long)'DISPLAYS NAME BACK ON EXCEL FILE In COLUMN 2'
   For i = 1 To num_names
    Cells(i, 2) = names(i)
   Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error because it cannot find the `Shift` Procedure

```
Call shift
```

Also you need to pass parameters for Sub `display` else you will get an "Argument Not Optional" Error.

For example

```
Call display(1, 1)
'OR Simply
display 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need list all names?

Try this...

```
Sub ListNames()
Dim N As Name

For Each N In ThisWorkbook.Names
    Debug.Print N.RefersTo
Next N

End Sub
```